# Can this if-statement be a switch-statement and prettier or simplified?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, switch-statement, refactoring

Can this if-statement be a switch-statement and prettier or simplified?

```
items = function () {
    n = $(item).length;

    if (n % 4 == 3){
        $(foo).addClass(small);
    } else if (n % 4 == 2){
        $(foo).addClass(medium);
    } else if (n % 4 == 1){
        $(foo).addClass(large);
    } else if (n % 4 == 0){
        $(foo).addClass(xlarge);
    } 
};
```

Comment: Yes, it could be a switch statement.  Does it need to be a switch statement?  No.

Comment: You've asked two questions; if it can be a switch statement and how to make it prettier/simplified.  The first is an opinion question, and the second is too broad. @ToE

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You might find this useful: http://examples.yourdictionary.com/examples-of-open-ended-and-closed-ended-questions.html

Comment: @freedomn-m, thank you for the link, I'll check it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the results of `n % 4` are `0`, `1`, `2` and `3` you could use an array of classes where each class index correspond to one of the previous results:

```
items = function () {
    n = $(item).length;

    $(foo).addClass([xlarge, large, medium, small][n % 4]);  
};
```

You see, depending on the value of `n % 4` an item of the array `[xlarge, large, medium, small]` will be selected, for example, if `n % 4` is `2` then `medium` will get selected and passed to `addClass`.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation @ibrahim mahrir!